# How to make std::map::find function case sensitive?

Tags: c++, c++11, find, stdmap, std

I had interviewed with a MNC company. He gave me the following code and asked me to make `find()` function as case-sensitive. I tried, but failed to understand how to make inbuilt find function as case-sensitive. Is there any way to make it case-sensitive to find only a particular key value?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<string, int> mp;
    mp["Test"] = 1;
    mp["test"] = 2;
    mp["TEST"] = 3;
    mp["tesT"] = 4;    

    for (auto it = mp.find("TEST"); it != mp.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << it->first << " " << it->second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
TEST 3
Test 1
tesT 4
test 2
```

But I expect output is:

```
TEST 3
```

Comment: The question makes no sense. Find is already case-sensitive, and it finds only one element on the map. You iterate using the iterator returned by find, and essentially, iterate over all your map - but it doesn't mean find is case-insenstitive. Try replacing map elements other than `TEST` with anything starting with `Z` - you will see the same result.

Comment: Short version: You don't need to enumerate-to-end every iterator you ever get from a standard container. If what you want is discovered, the iterator will refer to it; if it is not found, the iterator will be `mp.end()`. it really is that simple. I have no idea why you're using an enumeration loop, and what force on earth told you to do so, but whatever it was/is, it's wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the for loop. You do not need to iterate through the map to print it. Rather you need to do

```
auto it = mp.find("TEST");
if (it != mp.end())
    std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second << std::endl;
```

The `std::map::find` will find an iterator pointing to the key-value pair which has key exactly `"TEST"`, if not found just the end iterator.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that it's finding "TEST", then you're iterating through the remainder of the map, and printing out everything that came after that.

As it happens, in most common character sets, upper case letters sort before lower case letters, so `TEST` is going to be the first item in the `map`. So when you print things out starting from there, you end up printing out all the items.

But a `map` can only hold one item with a particular key, so there's no real reason to iterate. You either found the one item (`it != container.end()`) or you didn't (`it == container.end()`).

If you were using a `multimap`, there could be multiple items with the same key. In that case, you'd typically want to use `std::equal_range` to find all the items with that one key. That'll return a pair of iterators, one to the start of the range, and the other one past the end of the range  of items with that key. You'd then print out all the items in the range it returned.